# How can I check if textarea (tinymce) only contains space?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I have a form using Tinymce, I need to check if it only contains space.

I try using this function

```
function validation_form()
{
    var content = tinyMCE.get('main-comment').getContent().replace('&nbsp;','');
    if(content == "" || content == null || content == '<p> </p>') {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But it returns **true** when I input several spaces and submit, I want  it to return false instead.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks,

Comment: *"But it return true when..."* - No it doesn't. The function shown returns either `false` or `undefined`, it *never* returns `true`.

Comment: sr, not return true. But if it don't return false, the form will submit. I have called it in form by onsubmit='return validation_form()'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use [$.trim](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) ,

it is clean and readable.

```
function validation_form()
{
    var content = $.trim(tinyMCE.get('main-comment').getContent({format: 'text'}));
    if(content.length == 0) {
        return false;
    }
   return true;
}
```

Updated: **format as text**, to get text content from editor. [check fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/rs8ht0qb/)

Comment: @VietHuongBui check the updated anwer, i guess this is what you looking for

Answer (score 1):

-- Originally wrote it in PHP --

```
function validation_form()
{
    var content = $.trim(tinyMCE.get('main-comment').getContent());
    if(content.length == 0) {
        return false;
    }
   return true;
}
```

Is Correct @A.T

Comment: Not work!, I type one space and it return true; I write this function in javascript, not php

Comment: I wrote this in php originally, I am sorry, I am really tired and on my phone. Empty is a function in php to determine if whatever you're testing has any value to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript's `trim` method.

`function validation_form()
{
    var content = tinyMCE.get('main-comment').getContent().replace('&nbsp;','').trim();
    if(content == "" || content == null || content == '<p> </p>') {
        return false;
    }
}`

For more information, please check [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Solution for the same while using **Angular Reactive Form Validation**

Give this custom validator function in typescript file

```
emptyLinesValiadtor(control:FormControl):{[s:string]:boolean} | null {
let content = control.value.replaceAll(/&nbsp;/gm,'')
.trim().split(" ").join("").replaceAll('<p></p>','').trim();
if(content == "" || content == null) {
  return  {'emptyLines': true}
}
return null;
}
```

In your Reactive form builder/declaration

```
 this.formName= this.formBuilder.group({
 textArea:['',this.emptyLinesValiadtor]
 });
```

In your template form

```
  <div
        *ngIf="sForm.submitted && f.textArea.errors">
        <div *ngIf="f.textArea.errors.emptyLines">
          <div>Answer cannot contain empty lines/spaces</div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

where sform is reference variable and f is a typescript get method like below

```
get f() {
return this.formName.controls;
}
```